# How to share the same Azure service connection across tasks in the same release pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a classic (non-YAML) release pipeline with multiple tasks requiring a service connection to the Azure portal.
At the moment I need to specify this connection in every single task, but I was wondering if there was a way to set it at either the pipeline or job level and then inherit through the various tasks.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a task group for the tasks that have already specified the service connection, so that when you need to use these tasks next time, you don't need to reconfigure them. Just import your configured task group in the agent job.

[image]

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion. 
Unfortuantely, this option isn't ideal since for each enviroment/stage I have multiple jobs and they all need to share the same service connection. I can only group tasks under the same job.
So far, the best option I've found was to create the pipeline manually, export the template, edit the file to add some pipeline parameters and re-import the pipeline. It's a shame that Azure DevOps doesn't allow to add pipeline parameters from the UI.